# zend 2: Using Paginator with TableGateway

Tags: sql, design-patterns, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I have my models configured in Module.php like this:

```
'MyModule\Model\MyTable' => function($sm) {
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('MyTableGateway');
    $table = new MyTable($tableGateway);
    return $table;
},
'MyTableGateway' => function($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(
        new Ticket());
    return new TableGateway('someTable', $dbAdapter, null,
        $resultSetPrototype);
    },
```

Now I'm doing this in MyTable.php:

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(
    function(Select $select) {
        $select
            ->order('id ASC')
            ->where->equalTo('aaaa', 2343)
            ->and
            ->where->notEqualTo('bbbb', 'sdfsdf')
            ;
});
```

Now I want to use pagination, but looking at the [zend tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/tutorial.pagination.html) they have you do this:

```
// create a new Select object for the table album
$select = new Select('someTable');
// create a new result set based on the Album entity
$resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
// create a new pagination adapter object
$paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
    // our configured select object
    $select,
    // the adapter to run it against
    $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
    // the result set to hydrate
    $resultSetPrototype
);
$paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
return $paginator;
```

Why must I do `$select = new Select('someTable');` Doesn't this violate DI principles because I'm statically inputting the table's name? It does seem right to have the table name configured in Module.php AND yet still have to hard code it in the actual model. Can I retrieve the table name from the service manager somehow?

Comment: `$select = new Select($this->tableGateway->getTable());` ?

Comment: Great that was easy. I'm also setting the resultSetPrototype in the model, is there a why to just pull that from Module.php as well?

Comment: Never mind I think getResultSetPrototype() is what I want

Comment: Take a look at the available methods of the table gateway, `getResultSetPrototype()` looks like what you need -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php (edit: I see you found it already :o) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what my code looks like now as per Crisp's comments

```
$select = new Select($this->tableGateway->getTable());

$paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
    $select,
    $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
    $this->tableGateway->getResultSetPrototype()
);
$paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);

return $paginator;
```

Weird they didn't do it like this in the tutorial.